# Interactive ssh session started from bash command

Tags: bash, ssh, xargs

I'm trying to launch an interactive ssh session created from a bash command (as shown below).

If I do not add the 'ttt', I just get a 'non interactive' session message and the ssh session is closed.

After adding the 'ttt' flag, the session remains open but I can not enter commands or interact with the remote session.

This is a simplified version of the command I'm trying to execute

```
 echo "username@host" | xargs -I{} bash -x -c 'ssh -ttt" $0' {}
```

**Not sure if there is an additional flag that should be added or alternative way of doing this.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input to `xargs` (and therefore `bash` and therefore `ssh`) is coming from the pipe, not your terminal. Depending on the larger context, one of these options should work to let `ssh` read from the terminal:

- Capture the list of hosts to an array first, then use a `for` loop instead of `xargs`. Something like this:

  ```
   readarray -t hostarray < <(echo "username@host")
   for host in "${hostarray[@]}"; do
       ssh "$host"
   done
  ```
- Add the `-o` option to `xargs`, which tells it to redirect stdin of the command from /dev/tty (i.e. the terminal).
- Redirect the regular stdin around the `xargs` command via a different file descriptor, e.g. #3 (note: I haven't tested this):

  ```
   { echo "username@host" | xargs -I{} bash -x -c 'ssh -ttt "$0" <&3' {}; } 3<&0
  ```

BTW, in addition to problems with `ssh` not getting input it's supposed to get (i.e. from the terminal), you can also have trouble with it stealing input that was intended for something else, like parts of the list of hosts you wanted `xargs` to read. See [BashFAQ #89: I'm reading a file line by line and running ssh or ffmpeg, only the first line gets processed!](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089)

Comment: Awesome!. Second option worked for me. I'm gonna take a look to the post.